# club sets being invariant under increasing continuous function

Tags: set-theory

Can someone explain (prove) me why this holds?

To be precise, by club set I mean closed and unbounded set where given definitions are:

Let κ ∈ Card and C ⊆ κ . C is unbounded in κ if
∀α < κ ∃β ∈ C α < β.

C is closed in κ if ∀λ < κ (λ is a limit ordinal ∧ C ∩λ is unbounded in λ→λ ∈ C).

On the other hand, I am supposed to prove that the next thing holds:

Suppose that µ, κ are regular cardinals and f∶µ → κ is a cofinal strictly
increasing continuous function. I have to show that f[C] is club in κ for every
club C in µ

Comment: I've heard of cofinal sets, but what is a cofinal function? Do you mean an unbounded function?

Comment: Yes, unbounded one

Comment: @bof A function is cofinal if its range is. If the codomain is a total order is almost the same as unbounded (though it differs if the codomain has a maximum element), but it's completely different if the codomain is not total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: A cofinal continuous and strictly increasing function $\mu\to \kappa$ extends to a continuous function $\mu+1\to \kappa+1$ (because it implies that $\lim_{\alpha \to \mu} f(\alpha)=\kappa$), which are compact Hausdorff spaces. Being closed in $\kappa$ or $\mu$ is the same as being closed in the order topology. This helps with the "closed" part. The "unbounded" part should be obvious. (In  fact, I belive you don't need to know anything about $\mu$ and $\kappa$ here -- they can be any limit ordinals.)

Comment: I have also done the unboundedness part, but still I don't get how this hint helps. Sorry for disturbing

Comment: @Eurydice: Continuous maps between compact Hausdorff spaces are closed.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: I like **tomasz**’s argument, but a more elementary one is also possible.

If $f[C]$ is not closed in $\kappa$, let $\alpha=\min\big((\operatorname{cl}f[C])\setminus C\big)$, and let $A=C\cap\alpha$; clearly $\alpha\in\operatorname{cl}A$. Let $B=f^{-1}[A]=\{\xi\in C:f(\xi)<\alpha\}$, and let $\beta=\sup B\in C$. There are two possibilities: either $\beta=\max B\in B$, or $B\subseteq\beta$. Show that each possibility leads to a contradiction.